# Trouble tracking Ajax forms in Analytics

Tags: ajax, form-submit, event-tracking

I'm not sure if I have analytics set up correctly to track the Ajax form submission or if I need to change something in my code on the page. If anyone can look at the code I would really appreciate it.

Tried setting up event tracking for the page in Analytics, not sure if that is correct. Page is https://www.aaacredit.net/contact.html

```
<form name="contactForm" class="customform ajax-form text-dark" action="resp-contact.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactForm">
<div class="line">
 <div class="margin">
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-12">
<input name="name" type="text" class="required name" placeholder="Your full name" title="Your full name" id="name"/>
<p class="name-error form-error">Please enter your full name.</p>
</div>


<div class="s-12 m-12 l-12">
<input name="company" class="company" placeholder="Your company" title="Your company" type="text" id="company"/>
<p class="name-error form-error">Please enter company name. (if any)</p>
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
<input name="email" class="required email" placeholder="Your e-mail" title="Your e-mail" type="text" id="email" />
<p class="email-error form-error">Please enter your e-mail.</p>
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
<input name="phone" class="required phone" placeholder="Your phone number" title="Your phone number" type="tel" id="phone"/>
<p class="email-error form-error">Please enter your phone number.</p>
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
<input name="city" class="city" placeholder="Your city" title="Your city" type="text" id="city"/>
<p class="email-error form-error">Please enter your city.</p>
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">

<select name="state" class="required" title="Your state" id="state">
<option value="">Your State</option>

<--I removed all the states to make it easier to read -->   
</select>

<p class="email-error form-error">Please enter your state.</p>
</div>

<div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
<input name="zip" class="zip code" placeholder="Your zip code" title="Your zip code" type="text" id="zip"/>
<p class="email-error form-error">Please enter your zip code.</p>
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-6">
<select name="found" class="required" title="I found you from" id="found">
<option value="">I found you from</option>
<option value="Advertisement">Advertisement</option>
<option value="Alignable">Alignable</option>
<option value="Email Advertisement">Email Advertisement</option>
<option value="Google">Google</option>
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
<option value="Referral">Referral</option>
<option value="Seminar">Seminar</option>
<option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
<option value="Word of Mouth">Word of Mouth</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>   
<option value="I am an Existing Client">I am an existing client</option>     
</select>            
<p class="email-error form-error">How did you find us?</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>            

<div class="line">       

<div class="s-12">
<textarea name="message" class="required message" placeholder="Comments" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
<p class="message-error form-error">Comments</p>
</div>
<div class="s-12">
<input type="file" name="file[]" />                    
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-12">

<p class="text-size-16 text-strong text-lblue">Please click on I am not a robot, wait for check mark and then click submit. Thank you!</p>
<br><br> </div>
<!-- full-name-field is hidden antirobot field -->
<input name="full-name-field" type="text" id="full-name-field" class="full-name-field" />
<div class="s-12">

<a class="captcha-button text-white background-green border-radius margin-bottom">
<span class="not-a-robot-icon"><i class="icon-check text-white"></i></span> 

<span class="not-a-robot-text">I'm not a robot</span>
</a>
</div> 
<!-- The submit button text you can edit in the file validation.sj on the line 8. -->
<div class="s-12 button-parent"></div>
<div class="line">
<p class="mail-success form-success">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
<p class="mail-fail form-error">Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.</p>
</div>
</div>    
</form>
```

I can provide screen shots of how I set up the events in Google Tag Manager, don't see a way to add images here, though.